# Is there a way to remove this vertical line in the R script background (R Studio 2020 version)

Tags: rstudio

[image: screenshot of vertical line]

There is a vertical line that shows up automatically in the background of my blank R script - I have just downloaded the latest version of RStudio 2020. Any way to get a clear white view of the script without the line? thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a "margin" which shows you when code gets to a certain width.  Lots of people/standards choose to limit code width so that it's easier to read on the screen and if you decide to print it it won't overflow to the next line.  To disable in Rstudio (at least my version of Rstudio...) in the top toolbar:

`Tools -> Global Options -> Code` (located in the sidebar) then choose the Display tab and uncheck the `Show margin` option.

Comment: Thank you so much! The line was annoying me so much and this worked perfectly. :)